# Is asking about the events depicted in a "biographical" movie on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question ["Why no weapons aboard ship?"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/42226/why-no-weapons-aboard-ship) isn't on topic in my opinion, and this is backed up by the question's opening line:

> While **my question regards piracy in general**, the movie Captain
>   Phillips is what brought it on due to it being a true story.

The question itself is obviously not about the movie, but about the events depicted in the movie:

> why in hell if you are going to drive a ship full of cargo worth
>   millions, through pirate waters, you wouldn't have weapons?

I'm tempted to flag it for closure for being off-topic, but none of the available reasons seem applicable.

Comment: Uh, in general: *"none of the available reasons seem applicable"* - That is exactly why there exists a custom close-reason where you have to come up with a proper explanation yourself.